# How to use FpSread.SaveExcel to save multiple grid data into multiple sheets of same excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net

This is what I have tried so far

```
If SaveExcel.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            gridCli.SaveExcel(SaveExcel.FileName,"Clients" FarPoint.Excel.ExcelSaveFlags.UseOOXMLFormat Or FarPoint.Excel.ExcelSaveFlags.SaveCustomColumnHeaders)
            gridFin_Trans.SaveExcel(SaveExcel.FileName,"Financials" FarPoint.Excel.ExcelSaveFlags.UseOOXMLFormat Or FarPoint.Excel.ExcelSaveFlags.SaveCustomColumnHeaders)
            portfolioGrid.SaveExcel(SaveExcel.FileName,"Sheet3" FarPoint.Excel.ExcelSaveFlags.UseOOXMLFormat Or FarPoint.Excel.ExcelSaveFlags.SaveCustomColumnHeaders)

End If
```

Here I should tell what went wrong:

> ...

Comment: Got it Figured out

Comment: To save the sheets to the same Excel workbook, you need to add the sheets to one instance of FpSpread, then save that using SaveExcel.
create a new FpSpread, adding those sheets to it using FpSpread.Sheets.Add, then call FpSpread.SaveExcel

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

To save the sheets to the same Excel workbook, you need to add the sheets to one instance of `FpSpread`, then save that using SaveExcel.

- create a new FpSpread,
- adding those sheets to it using `FpSpread.Sheets.Add`,
- then call * `FpSpread.SaveExcel` *